# Office 365: Outlook — limit sync to 30 days

Tags: macos, email, data-synchronization, ms-office, gmail

I have just installed MS Outlook for Mac and am trying to prevent it from downloading my entire inbox with emails dating back to 2008.

I have an IMAP Gmail account and only want Outlook to sync emails from the 30 most recent days. This is quite easy to achieve in Thunderbird but I can't see anything for this for Outlook?

Answer (score 2):

As of Outlook 16.23 (February 2019), such a feature to limit the email downloaded by date does not appear to exist. There's a feature request on [Outlook's UserVoice forum](https://outlook.uservoice.com/forums/293343-outlook-for-mac/suggestions/13153866--mail-to-keep-offline) for this functionality.

For an IMAP account, under the account's Advanced settings, you can configure Outlook to only download headers.

[image: screenshot of the location of the Advance button under an account's settings]

[image: screenshot of the download headers only option checkbox]

There is nothing similar for Exchange accounts.

Answer (score 0):

If you set up your Gmail account as a regular IMAP account (and not as a gmail account) in Outlook, you can limit the download size.  For this, you would also need to change your IMAP settings in Gmail.  There is an option to restrict the number of messages that can be synced. I have set it to 1000.  This does not work by number of days, but close enough if you can guess a number for yourself.